# how can I shape the image size according to its nested box

Tags: javascript, css, user-interface, layout

there is a web site called: `SPAM`
I am trying to make the same home page of this web site using js, jquery and some css.

Now, the question is how to fix the image size according to the box in the center.
How can I create best user experience as if `SPAM` has.

You may experience by viewing the web site of `SPAM` in different 
resolution or small and big windows size of explorer.

How can I do it? Answers and code help or suggestions for the best user experience for `SPAM` ?

Comment: @hi ho1, why do you consider the links as a spam? If you delete it how can I describe my question ?

Comment: @one more think for my question, I want the logo , the menus and the footer just below and above of the box in the center. how can i do that?

Comment: No, I'm inclined to agree - the emphasis of this question seems to be the URL, not the issue. Anyone reading the question can get that from the [edited] link above my name/

Comment: (to put this in context, the question was about to be automatically deleted due to accumulating spam votes from users; a deleted question is even harder to answer...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is flash... but you can do the same with some jQuery:

html:

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

css:

```
#container {
    min-width: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative
    background: url('path') 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(window).bind("resize", function() {
    var $winwidth = $(window).width(); //specify some padding here
    $("#container").attr({
        width: $winwidth
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To start, make the `<did id='main'>` to take the width of the screen

```
#main { width:100% }
```

then, the image(s) inside should have a similar styling:

```
#main img { width:100% }
```

please note that the image height is not set, to make it automatically scale with the right proportions.

This should help to obtain an effect similar to the mentioned site.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

on the inner element so it is horizontally aligned.